# Retrofit2 Cache Confusion

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I can cache responses according to samples but I can't understand cache mechanism even I read many article about the topic. In retrofit2 we are using interceptors and rewrite request headers. Sample code,

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var request = chain.request()
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control",
                "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24).build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
    return chain.proceed(request)
}
```

But we manipulate request headers, shouldn't cache work according to response headers?

And is there any good article about cache mechanism including useful headers?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You're settling the cache control header in the request and not the response. This is usually done to either obtain a cached response from the proxies in the route to the server, or force revalidation of the resource by setting the header to `no cache`. Also if you do want to change it in the response, you'd probably need to add it as a network interceptor. How are you adding this

Comment: I am trying to enable offline caching with retrofit2 according to response headers. In my case i have a global response which includes cache info as integer and a generic data, so i am trying to manipulate headers according to integer value which is in global response using interceptors. But i have to understand the entire caching mechanism.

Comment: So the code you have is basically adding a header that says "get only if it's cached", meaning, it won't request any data if not cached and the max-stale will only accept cached data that is less than one day old. This has to be done in the request so okhtt please knows what to do. I hope this at least helps you a bit